# Mongodb group and sort by date from subdocument

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following mongodb documents

```
 { 
    "_id" : ISODate("2016-01-04T23:00:11.000+0000"), 
    "value" : {
        "hour" : ISODate("2016-01-04T23:00:00.000+0000"), 
        "day" : ISODate("2016-01-04T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
        "time" : ISODate("2016-01-04T23:00:11.000+0000"), 
        "day_chan1" : 90.162, 
        "day_chan2" : 77.547, 
        "day_chan3" : 79.32, 
        "total_day_chan" : 247.029
    }
}
{ 
    "_id" : ISODate("2016-01-04T23:00:23.000+0000"), 
    "value" : {
        "hour" : ISODate("2016-01-04T23:00:00.000+0000"), 
        "day" : ISODate("2016-01-04T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
        "time" : ISODate("2016-01-04T23:00:23.000+0000"), 
        "day_chan1" : 90.167, 
        "day_chan2" : 77.549, 
        "day_chan3" : 79.322, 
        "total_day_chan" : 247.038
    }
}
{ 
    "_id" : ISODate("2016-01-04T23:00:35.000+0000"), 
    "value" : {
        "hour" : ISODate("2016-01-04T23:00:00.000+0000"), 
        "day" : ISODate("2016-01-04T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
        "time" : ISODate("2016-01-04T23:00:35.000+0000"), 
        "day_chan1" : 90.172, 
        "day_chan2" : 77.551, 
        "day_chan3" : 79.324, 
        "total_day_chan" : 247.047
    }
}
```

where I want to group and sort the documents based on the day subdocument, so all the data will from the same day will come out in an array.

So far I tried using

```
.aggregate([{
                        '$sort': {
                            '_id': 1
                        }
                    },
                    {
                         '$group' : {
                             '_id': '$value.day',
                             'data': {                                    
                                 '$push' : '$value'
                             }
                         }

                    },                        
                    {
                        '$project': {
                            '_id' : 1,
                            'data':1
                        }
                    }
      ]);
```

But I noticed data from two seperate dates coming into the same array

Here is what I get inside one of the arrays

```
  { hour: Tue Jan 05 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT),
  day: Tue Jan 05 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT),
  time: Tue Jan 05 2016 00:00:12 GMT+0000 (GMT),
  day_chan1: 91.635,
  day_chan2: 78.274,
  day_chan3: 80.062,
  total_day_chan: 249.971 }
{ hour: Mon Jan 04 2016 23:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT),
  day: Mon Jan 04 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT),
  time: Mon Jan 04 2016 23:00:11 GMT+0000 (GMT),
  day_chan1: 90.162,
  day_chan2: 77.547,
  day_chan3: 79.32,
  total_day_chan: 247.029 }
```

But ideally these two should be in seperate arrays

```
          [{ hour: Tue Jan 05 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT),
      day: Tue Jan 05 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT),
      time: Tue Jan 05 2016 00:00:12 GMT+0000 (GMT),
      day_chan1: 91.635,
      day_chan2: 78.274,
      day_chan3: 80.062,
      total_day_chan: 249.971 }, {
},{ hour: Tue Jan 05 2016 00:0:00 GMT+0000 (GMT),
      day: Tue Jan 05 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT),
      time: Tue Jan 05 2016 01:01:12 GMT+0000 (GMT),
      day_chan1: 91.635,
      day_chan2: 78.274,
      day_chan3: 80.062,
      total_day_chan: 249.971 }],
     [{ hour: Mon Jan 04 2016 23:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT),
      day: Mon Jan 04 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT),
      time: Mon Jan 04 2016 23:00:11 GMT+0000 (GMT),
      day_chan1: 90.162,
      day_chan2: 77.547,
      day_chan3: 79.32,
      total_day_chan: 247.029 }]
```

All the documents for the same day would be collected in an array

[Array for Date1, Array for Date2, Array for date3 ] and so on.

Comment: Can you show us what is your expected output and what are you are getting out of the command?

Comment: I am running the same command as you have provided and getting the correct result.

Comment: I have 40,000 documents so the error occurs at some point.

Comment: data from two days get collected into the same array.

Answer (score 1):

The example documents you have provided are of same dates. So I changed date of one of the document and then ran the command which you have provide and got the following result.

```
{
    "_id" : ISODate("2016-01-05T00:00:00Z"),
    "data" : [
        {
            "hour" : ISODate("2016-01-05T23:00:00Z"),
            "day" : ISODate("2016-01-05T00:00:00Z"),
            "time" : ISODate("2016-01-05T23:00:11Z"),
            "day_chan1" : 90.162,
            "day_chan2" : 77.547,
            "day_chan3" : 79.32,
            "total_day_chan" : 247.029
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ISODate("2016-01-04T00:00:00Z"),
    "data" : [
        {
            "hour" : ISODate("2016-01-04T23:00:00Z"),
            "day" : ISODate("2016-01-04T00:00:00Z"),
            "time" : ISODate("2016-01-04T23:00:23Z"),
            "day_chan1" : 90.167,
            "day_chan2" : 77.549,
            "day_chan3" : 79.322,
            "total_day_chan" : 247.038
        },
        {
            "hour" : ISODate("2016-01-04T23:00:00Z"),
            "day" : ISODate("2016-01-04T00:00:00Z"),
            "time" : ISODate("2016-01-04T23:00:35Z"),
            "day_chan1" : 90.172,
            "day_chan2" : 77.551,
            "day_chan3" : 79.324,
            "total_day_chan" : 247.047
        }
    ]
}
```

So according to me I could not find any problem.